# why is it bad to double hash a string (encrpyt)?

Tags: php, encryption

i heard on another site that doing something like is a bad idea:

```
$string = "hello";
sha1(hash("sha512", $string));
```

... as far as i am concerned its a good, clever idea! why is it not? (i did not quite understand the explanation on the other site)

Thanks

Comment: Can you link a reference to where you read it? Maybe we can provide some context.  Multiple rounds of hashing is not uncommon. If done with a slow algorithm it creates a kind of rate-limit against brute-force attacks.

Comment: this is the site http://phpacademy.org/forum/, but annoyingly its under some technical issues

Comment: would you recommend it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348109/is-double-hashing-a-password-less-secure-than-just-hashing-it-once - almost duplicated

Comment: One advantage is that the hash will most likely not be in any lookup table with known hashes.

Comment: oh, like a rainbow table..

Comment: @CasparWylie Read over the question linked by AppDeveloper. Good answer there...

Comment: sorry, did not realise some one else ask this...

Comment: Let me know if this helps:
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066215/hashing-a-string-for-use-in-hash-table-double-hashing/8102118#8102118

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with hashing multiple times. There are a number of cases where this is actually a good idea.

1. You want to slow down brute force attacks.
2. You have a databases full of hashed passwords that use a broken hashing scheme. Upgrading from MD5 to SHA1 for example.
3. You're implementing a challenge/response scheme.

Comment: what do you mean "You're implementing a challenge/response scheme."?

Comment: @Caspar If you want to verify that someone has the same key or salt that is stored on the server, the server could hash a randomly generated message using that key/salt and send it to the client.  The client would then use the key/salt to hash the hash and send back the double hash.  The server would then hash the original hash with the key again to compare that it matches what the client sent.

Answer (score 1):

The example you pasted is bad because you're hashing a 512-bit hash with a 160-bit hash.

Comment: It's probably just a quick and dirty example, rather than actual code the OP is using.